# Google search ajax api limit?

Tags: php, google-api

I'm using php to get search from google, and I have few qustions

1. is there a limit of queries per day ?
2. is there a limit of queries per minute ?
3. if the limit is reached, what is the response code I'll be getting from google? Is it a json response - same as good response or is it 404/400 header?

Thanks for answering questions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595001/how-many-requests-can-be-made-to-google-maps-api-without-ban

Comment: its talk about the maps api and not the search api

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest checking the documentation:

http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/documentation/

Comment: http://www.mail-archive.com/google-ajax-search-api@googlegroups.com/msg03826.html - might help too

Comment: about the answer : im there for 2 days now , cant find any answer to my qustions

Comment: about the comment : its from 2009 , for now i can get 10 results per page , and max of 65 results per search query

Comment: https://groups.google.com/group/google-ajax-search-api/browse_thread/thread/d9d509620ba95079 - more up-to-date

Comment: Basically, there is no limit to the number of times your can search, but there is a limit on the number of results it will return

Comment: But now there is a limit, no? 100 search queries per day. For more you need to pay :/

Comment: Over 2 years later I would imagine things will have changed, yes