# Google Maps - Too Many API Calls?

Tags: api, google-maps, threshold, pins

We are experiencing a problem where the pins on our map are not always appearing. Here is how our system is setup:

1. We have a C# script running which collects data from our website, pings Google with each location and then stores the data (Location Name, Lat, Long) in our database. This script runs every 10 minutes and normally makes 0 to 5 requests to Google.
2. We have a map which queries our database and uses the stored latitude and longitude information to plot the data on the map. There are usually 5 to 25 pins on the map at any given time.

My Question: Every time we add a pin to our map, does that count as an API request? Is it possible we are going over the requests/minute threshold because if the map is loaded 3 times in succession, we just made 75 calls to the API?

**UPDATE**
Okay, what appears to be happening is that if I wait a 5-10 minutes and then go to the page or reload the page, none of the pins show up. If I then reload the page, the 1st reload usually also results in zero pins. After that, I can reload as many times as I want and pins will appear every time...

Here is a link to the map: http://proplive.mkainc.com/map/map.php

**UPDATE 2**
The problem now appears to be with how we are fetching the data that is being used for the pins, not with how we are calling the Google Maps API.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How many requests can be made to Google Maps API without being banned?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595001/how-many-requests-can-be-made-to-google-maps-api-without-being-banned)

Comment: I'm asking if each pin creation counts as an API call.

Comment: Each geocode request counts as an API call. Creating a pin *itself* is not a call.